# How to filter documents in Mongoose model with data from another models

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

For example, I have 3 models:

Stories:

```
{
    title: { type: String },
    text: { type: String }
}
```

Comments:

```
{
    text: { type: String },
    story: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Stories" }
}
```

Likes:

```
{
    story: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Stories" }
}
```

How can I get the most popular stories, if popularity is determined by the amount of comments and likes? Story is more popular if it has more comments and likes, for example.

Thanks.

**Upd: example data.**

```
Stories: 
{
  "title": "First story",
  "text": "This must be the MOST popular story..."
}

{
  "title": "Second story",
  "text": "This story is popular too, but not as the first story."
}

{
  "title": "Third story",
  "text": "This is a unpopular story, because dont have any comment or like"
}


Comments:
{
  "title": "Foo",
  "story": ObjectId("First Story ID")
}

{
  "title": "Foobar",
  "story": ObjectId("First Story ID")
}

{
  "title": "Bar",
  "story": ObjectId("Second Story ID")
}


Likes:
{ "story": ObjectId("First Story ID") }
{ "story": ObjectId("First Story ID") }
{ "story": ObjectId("First Story ID") }
{ "story": ObjectId("First Story ID") }

{ "story": ObjectId("Second Story ID") }
{ "story": ObjectId("Second Story ID") }

{ "story": ObjectId("Third Story ID") }
```

The result of filtering should be like this:

1. First story (4 likes, 2 comments)
2. Second story (2 likes, 1 comment)
3. Third story (1 like)

Comment: How do you determine the popularity metrics? Which is more popular, a story with _5 comments and 100 likes_ OR a story with _100 comments and 5 likes_?

Comment: @chridam 5 comments and 100 likes.

Comment: @chridam At the moment, I want to understand the logic. This question contains example data

Comment: Where is the example data? I can only see the schema definitions. Is it ok if you could use the [edit] link to add some sample documents from both `Comments` and `Likes` models and your expected result?

Comment: @chridam please see the update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to sort data according to **popularity** where popularity is defined by **(total like + total comments )** then you can use this `aggregate` query with `$lookup`.

```
db.getCollection('stories').aggregate([
{$lookup:{from:"comments",localField:"_id", foreignField:"story", as:"comments"}},
{$lookup:{from:"likes",localField:"_id", foreignField:"story", as:"likes"}},
{ $project: { title: 1, text: 1,comments:1,likes:1, count: { $add: [ {$size: "$comments"}, {$size: "$likes"} ] } } },
{$sort:{"count":-1}}
])
```

for mongoose:

```
StoryModelName.aggregate([
    {$lookup:{from:"comments",localField:"_id", foreignField:"story", as:"comments"}},
    {$lookup:{from:"likes",localField:"_id", foreignField:"story", as:"likes"}},
    { $project: { title: 1, text: 1,comments:1,likes:1, count: { $add: [ {$size: "$comments"}, {$size: "$likes"} ] } } },
    {$sort:{"count":-1}}
    ]).exec(function(err, values) {
       if(err) {
          // return error
       }     
       // return values 
    })
```

**OR** if you want to sort by **likes then comments** or **comments then like**.

can use this query:

```
StoryModelName.aggregate([
{$lookup:{from:"comments",localField:"_id", foreignField:"story", as:"comments"}},
{$lookup:{from:"likes",localField:"_id", foreignField:"story", as:"likes"}},
{$group:{_id:"$_id", 
    totalLikes: {$sum:{$size: "$likes"}}, 
    totalComments:{$sum:{$size: "$comments"}},
    likes:{$first:"$likes"},
    comments:{$first:"$comments"}
    }
},
{$sort:{totalLikes:-1,totalComments:-1}} // can be comments ten like as you need
]).exec(function(err, values) {
   if(err) {
      // return error
   }     
   // return values 
})
```

Comment: Great, thank you! It is exactly what i'm looking for.